# Is there a software program that calculates the Transfer Function for a given circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, software

I'm asking for a program (either freeware or not) where you can draw your circuit as the input, as it happens in PSPice, Multisim, LTSpice etc.., then specify two nodes of reference, say \$ V_{out} \$ and \$V_{in}\$, or \$V_1\$ and \$I_2\$ and then the program outputs the transfer function e.g. \$ V_{out}(s)/V_{in}(s) \$ (preferably in the s-plane), or some impedance function \$V_{in}(s)/I_{in}(s)\$ or any function accordingly. In my opinion this would be the perfect program to check your circuit analysis on the s-plane.

For example if you draw this Sallen-key circuit in the following picture

[image]

and specify your nodes of reference \$ V_{out} \$ and \$V_{in}\$, it will output the transfer function above (in terms of the circuit components not the values they have, just like in the picture). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Virtually any of simulators can do it.

Comment: Looking at LTSpice now. It has an AC Analysis simulation type. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: So why not to try it?

Comment: A sim is not going to spit out a nicely manicured transfer function like in your example. It will plot your AC response. It's up to you to verify the AC response matches the transfer function.

Comment: Taking specific values for the components, you can get a transient response from LTSpice then input Vin(t) and Vout(t) to Matlab's System ID toolbox, which will give you the Laplace TF

Comment: @EugeneSh., I think s/he wants a sensible formula as output, not just a plot of magnitude and phase.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra, normally we work the other way. We start with a formula, and then try to find a circuit that produces that response. In that case it is sensible to use the simulator to generate a numerical result and compare it with the results of evaluating the formula to see how well the circuit does its job.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're looking for software that gives you the *symbolic* (i.e. formula) result, *none* of those mentioned in the comments can do that, as far as I know. What you're looking for is called a [symbolic (as opposed to numerical) circuit analysis software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_circuit_analysis).

In practical terms, there's *free*, education-oriented piece of software which does it, well there's two of them in fact

- the original [SapWin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SapWin), free but not open source
- and the open source variant/successor/reimplementation [QSapecNG](http://qsapecng.sourceforge.net/)

Both have usability/interface quirks but are basically usable and save time in some cases of more complex non-standard networks.

There's also a non-free Mathematica plugin called [Analog Insydes](http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/insydes/) which can do this and is the Cadillac version basically because it can make use of Mathematica's formula simplification engine etc., which helps in some more hairy cases; they have a [30-day demo version](http://www.itwm.fraunhofer.de/en/departments/system-analysis-prognosis-and-control/electronics-mechanics-mechatronics/analoginsydes/product-description/demo-version-download.html) freely available.

The list above in non-exhaustive, but stuff I've used occasionally and know to work. Besides those, supposedly TINA v10 (this is not the v9 free TI version) [can do it too](http://www.tina.com/symbolic_analysis) but I've not tried it. Also [Syrup for Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=127001) is a free add-on but not terribly well maintained. MATLAB by itself [has no built-in function for this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/122517) as far as I know; well, I found a free [add-on for it called SCAM](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/mna/MNA6.html) just now, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: This was the word i was looking for "symbolic". I'm still learning my way around scientific english nomenclature, as my native language isn't english. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes - I also can recommend SAPWIN. It provides more than "only" a symbolic ac analysis (s domain). It gives you the time domain step and impulse response as well as the pole-zero distribution in the complex s-plane (also as numbers). Very versatile. However, you cannot expect that the transfer function is given in the normalized form (as in your filter example). Hence, you must do some mathematical manupulations by yourself.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra: Your schematic is wrong. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Non-inverting_amplifier for the proper wiring.